# If element has class then run function, else run another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an element on my page that I want to make draggable.

On the click event I add the class 'active' this just expands my div and the image inside it.

So initially my div looks like...

```
<div class="work-showcase">
```

on click it becomes...

```
<div class="work-showcase active">
```

I want to say if the div has class active, perform X function, else perform Y.

```
$(body).click(function(){

        if($('.work-showcase').hasClass('active')){

            var bleft = 4900 ;
            var bright = $(window).width() - 200;

            $('.active > ul li').draggable({
                 axis: "x", 
                 revert: false,
                 stop: function(event, ui) {
                    if(ui.position.left < -bleft)
                    {   
                    $(this).animate({"left": "0px"}, 600);
                    }
                    if(ui.position.left > bright)
                    {   
                    $(this).animate({"left": "0px"}, 600);
                    }

                }
            });


            } else {


     var sleft = 1846 ;
     var sright = $(window).width() - 200;

            $('.work-showcase > ul li').draggable({
                 axis: "x", 
                 revert: false,
                 stop: function(event, ui) {
                    if(ui.position.left < -sleft)
                    {   
                    $(this).animate({"left": "0px"}, 600);
                    }
                    if(ui.position.left > sright)
                    {   
                    $(this).animate({"left": "0px"}, 600);
                    }

                }
            });

        }

    });
```

My If statement doesnt seem to work...

Comment: jQuery: `hasClass('classNameToCheck')`, native: `elem.className.indexOf('classNameToCheck') !== -1`

Comment: My if statement doesn't seem to work...

Comment: How it does not work? What should happen and what happens instead? condition in if statement is Ok. Never seen a problem with hasClass

Comment: It should do exactly the same, but more as a sidenote you could try : `if( $('.work-showcase').is('.active') ) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of what you currently have (let me know if there is a problem)

```
$('body').click(function () {
    var drag, left, right;

    if ($('.work-showcase').hasClass('active') === true) {
        drag = '.active > ul li';
        left = -4900;
        right = $(window).width() - 200;
    } else {
        drag = '.work-showcase > ul li';
        left = -1846;
        right = $(window).width() - 200;
    }

    $(drag).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        revert: false,
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left < left) {
                $(this).animate({'left': '0px'}, 600);
            } else if (ui.position.left > right) {
                $(this).animate({'left': '0px'}, 600);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works, only I have to click somewhere on the body to initiate it. Is there something I can do that would work better?

Comment: Well how would you rather initiate it?

Comment: I want it to always be checking i guess @RyanSmith, I add the active class on click, so the else wont work if I checked for a click on the work-showcase div would it, I'm debating whether a setInterval will be any good?

Comment: If you want it to be checking all the time use $(document).ready(function check() {...}); then inside the function called "check", at the very bottom, add setTimeout(check, 1000). Where 1000 is the time in milliseconds to wait. Would you like me to update my answer to reflect the change?

Answer (score 1):

This selector :

```
$(body).click(function(){ ... });
```

needs to be :

```
$('body').click(function(){ ... }
```

notice the quotes !

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
if($(this).hasClass("active")){
    //do this
} else {
    //do that
}
```

**Edit:** it returns `true` or `false`: [jQuery hasClass Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)